# Spring boot returning 200 status code for custom error pages

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to override the whitelabel error page. So as an example I have done this simple class:

```
@RestController
public class MyCustomErrorController implements ErrorController {

    private static final String PATH = "/error";

    @RequestMapping(value = PATH)
    public String error() {
        return "This is the error page";
    }

    @Override
    public String getErrorPath() {
        return PATH;
    }
}
```

I have taken my example from here:
https://gist.github.com/jonikarppinen/662c38fb57a23de61c8b

According to that gist, it actually has a comment like this:

```
// Appropriate HTTP response code (e.g. 404 or 500) is automatically set by Spring. 
// Here we just define response body.
```

However that's not what I'm seeing. For instance if I hit to a URL that I know that it should respond me a 500 status code (intentional `NullPointerException`), then that's what I should see, but when I hit to that URL I get a 200 response back with my error message ("This is the error page")

If I don't use this custom controller, then it shows me a 500 error page with the stacktrace on it, which is the default behavior. I have seen an old issue opened in 2014 here:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/684 that someone mentioning the same problem, however their solution is to show explicitly 500 responses, which does not really pass through the HTTP response code.

Just for the record, I actually put a breakpoint to `org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.sendError()` method. When this custom error controller does not exist, I can clearly see that `sendError()` method is being called with a status 500. However if I were to add HttpServletResponse argument to my `error()` method I do not see that the instance has 500 status code set.

Comment: Have a look at [this doc](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc) on Spring controller exception handling.

Answer (score 1):

#### Explanation

In the website example you provided, the `HttpStatus` is retrieved from the injected `HttpServletResponse`. 
So the following:

> Appropriate HTTP response code (e.g. 404 or 500) is automatically set by Spring.

means

> Spring sets it on the `HttpServletResponse` that he gets injected into his method as 
>   argument.

- He then has to retrieve the status and set it on his model `ErrorJson`.

#### Solution

To follow your example, you could change your method to this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = ERROR_MAPPING)
public ResponseEntity<String> error(HttpServletResponse response) {
    return new ResponseEntity<String>("This is the error page",
        HttpStatus.valueOf(response.getStatus()));
}
```

- I used `ResponseEntity<String>` instead of defining a custom object (a.k.a. `ErrorJson`).
- As I believe you know, alternatively to using the `HttpServletResponse`'s status, you could just set yours with `HttpStatus`.

Comment: Why do I set it as INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR? What if the response is 503? Why do I need to rewrite that?

Comment: Also for the given code, I get a `StatusExposingServletResponse` which is a case where the response code is defaulted to 200, so I always see a 200 error page for this case, if I were to remove this `MyCustomErrorController` class then I see a 500 error page with stack trace.

Comment: Not sure I understand. Using my answer's example, when an error occur, can you retrieve the correct HttpStatus with response.getStatus() ? The only reference I could find about StatusExposingServletResponse  is this: http://metrics.dropwizard.io/2.2.0/maven/apidocs/index.html?com/yammer/metrics/web/WebappMetricsFilter.html   Do you import this dependency ? Is this what you are using ? If I understand, the injected Response is a StatusExposingServletResponse which is always status 200 ?  If so, you need to include more details in your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are simply returning a message from one method, which is not an error as per SpringBoot.

*Following method will help you to return http status code as you want :*

```
 @RequestMapping(value = PATH)
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> error() {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();

    String statusMessage = "This is the error page";
        String statusCode = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value();

        map.put(STATUS_CODE, statusCode);
        map.put(STATUS_MESSAGE, statusMessage);

        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(map);
    }
```